# sql copy specific columns from one table to another table

Tags: sql-server, database

In the *sql server* I have a Codes table in `DevDB`. It has 10 columns. There is a *foreign key* column as `ParentCodeID`, *int column*.

I need to copy 5 columns excluding the *int* column to the `TestDB`. But I need to include "33" as the `ParentcodeID` to this column.

There are like *250+ records*. I need to do this automatically.
Please help!!!!

Comment: on which condition do u want copy 5 columns to the TestDB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
INSERT INTO TestDB.dbo.Codes(Col1,Col2,Col3,....)
SELECT 33,col1,col2.... FROM DevDB.dbo.tblCode where ParentCodeID = xx
```

Answer (score 0):

You can automate even the generation of the script to avoid corrections in future if new columns would be added. Here is the code:

```
declare @tblName varchar(100),@FieldList varchar(max),@FieldListReplaced varchar(max),@sql varchar(max),@Field varchar(100),@ReplacedField varchar(100),@ReplaceWithValue varchar(100)

set @tblName='Codes'
set @ReplacedField='ParentcodeID'
set @ReplaceWithValue='33'
set @FieldList=','

declare cur_fieldlist cursor for 
select [Name] from sys.all_columns 
where object_id=(Select id from sysobjects where name=@tblName) and 
      is_computed=0 and (is_identity=0) 
order by column_id
open cur_fieldlist
fetch next from cur_fieldlist into @Field
while @@fetch_status = 0
begin
 set @FieldList=@FieldList+@Field+','
 fetch next from cur_fieldlist into @Field
end
close cur_fieldlist
deallocate cur_fieldlist

set @FieldListReplaced=replace(@FieldList,','+@ReplacedField+',',','+@ReplaceWithValue+',') /*to avoid replacement for several fields like ParentcodeID, ParentcodeID2, BigParentcodeID, BigParentcodeID2 etc. */
set @FieldList=substring(@FieldList,2,(len(@FieldList)-2))
set @FieldListReplaced=substring(@FieldListReplaced,2,(len(@FieldListReplaced)-2))

set @sql='INSERT INTO TestDB.dbo.'+@tblName+' ('+@FieldList+')
SELECT '+@FieldListReplaced+' FROM DevDB.dbo.'+@tblName+' WHERE 1=1 /* put your conditions here */'

print (@sql) --for checking

exec (@sql)
```